# Find the date at which a group of people will reach a target age sum

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions, calendar-computations

The goal is to find the date at which the sum of ages of a group of people will reach a certain number.

Though I seem to have found an approximative solution, some issues remains, that I don't know how to fix.

- Let $m$ be the number of individuals in the group: $m\in\mathbb{N}^*$
- Let $i$ be an index assigned to each individual: $i\in\mathbb{N}^*,i\leq{m}$
- Let $a_i$ be the date at which the $i$<sup>th</sup> individual was born: $\forall{i},a_i\in\mathbb{Q}_+$
- Let $\lfloor{a_i}\rfloor$ be the year of birth and $\{a_i\}$ be the anniversary date regardless of the year: $a_i=\lfloor{a_i}\rfloor+\{a_i\}$
- Let's assume that individuals are sorted by their anniversaries dates: $\forall{i}<m, \{a_i\}\leq\{a_{i+1}\}$
- Let $x$ be the date we are looking for: $x\in\mathbb{Q}_{+},x=\lfloor{x}\rfloor+\{x\}$
- We are not looking for any date, but an anniversary date: $\{x\}\in\bigcup_{i=1}^{m}\left\{\{a_{i}\}\right\}$
- Finally, let $n$ be the sum of all individuals ages: $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$

We expect the sum of all individual ages to be $n$:

$$
n=\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor{x-a_{i}}\rfloor
$$

> At this point, I have to point out two flaws already:
>
> 1. Some individuals may be born at the same date, making it impossible for the ages sum to reach $n$ exactly (skiping from below $n$ to over $n$).
> 2. I didn't address the issue of bisextile years.

We can take out the years:

$$
n=\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor{x}\rfloor-\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor{a_{i}}\rfloor+\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor\{x\}-\{a_{i}\}\rfloor\\
n=m\lfloor{x}\rfloor-\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor{a_{i}}\rfloor+\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor\{x\}-\{a_{i}\}\rfloor
$$

- Given that $\{x\}$ is one of the $\{a_i\}$'s, we can let $j$ be such as: $j\in\mathbb{N}^*,j<m,\{a_j\}=\{x\}$

This allows us to break down the fractionnal parts sum into two sets:

$$
n=m\lfloor{x}\rfloor
-\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor{a_{i}}\rfloor
+\sum_{i=1}^j\lfloor\{a_j\}-\{a_{i}\}\rfloor
+\sum_{i=j+1}^m\lfloor\{a_j\}-\{a_{i}\}\rfloor
$$

Until $j$, the term of the sum is:

$$
\forall i\leq j,
\begin{cases}
\{a_{i}\}\leq\{a_j\}\\
\{a_j\}<1
\end{cases}
\Longrightarrow
0\leq\{a_j\}-\{a_{i}\}<1
\Longrightarrow
\lfloor\{a_j\}-\{a_{i}\}\rfloor=0
$$

After $j$, the term of the sum is:

$$
\forall i>j,
\begin{cases}
\{a_{i}\}\geq\{a_j\}\\
\{a_i\}\geq0
\end{cases}
\Longrightarrow
-1\leq\{a_j\}-\{a_{i}\}\leq0
\Longrightarrow
\lfloor\{a_j\}-\{a_{i}\}\rfloor=-1
$$

> Note: I assume here that $\{a_j\}-\{a_{i}\}<0$ though $\{a_j\}-\{a_{i}\}\leq0$, as per the "same date anniversary" remark before.

Now we can get rid of the fractionnal parts:

$$
n=m\lfloor{x}\rfloor
-\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor{a_{i}}\rfloor
+\sum_{i=1}^j0
+\sum_{i=j+1}^m{-1}
\\
n=m\lfloor{x}\rfloor
-\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor{a_{i}}\rfloor
-(m-(j+1))
$$

And isolate $j$ to find $x$

$$
j
=n
-m\lfloor{x}\rfloor
+\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor{a_{i}}\rfloor
+m
-1
\\
\{x\}=\{a_j\},j\equiv\left(
n
+\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor{a_{i}}\rfloor
-1
\right)[m]
\\
\lfloor{x}\rfloor
=\frac{n
+\sum_{i=1}^m\lfloor{a_{i}}\rfloor
+m-j-1}{m}
$$